# Finite ring extensions and finite field extensions

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R\subset S$ be two finitely generated integral domains over an algebraically closed field $k$. If $S$ is finite as $R$-module then $[L:K]<+\infty$, where $L$ and $K$ are the quotient fields of $S$ and $R$, respectively. Does the converse hold true? Any help is well accepted.

Comment: What about the integral domains $R = \mathbb{C}\left[t\right]$ and $S = \mathbb{C}\left[t,t^{-1}\right]$ over the field $k = \mathbb{C}$? Their quotient fields are the same.

Comment: Thanks. It was easy!